# WebLogic REST API - stop/start a JDBC Data Source

Tags: weblogic

How can I start/stop/reset a JDBC datasource in the new (12.2.1+) WebLogic REST API under
`/management/weblogic/latest`?

The old management REST API (12.1.3) had this endpoint with start/shutdown/reset as operations, which worked fine:
`/management/wls/latest/datasources/id/{id}`

I just cannot find JDBC control capabilities anywhere, eg. not here:

`/management/weblogic/latest/edit/JDBCSystemResources/{id}/`

`/management/weblogic/latest/serverRuntime/JDBCServiceRuntime/`

The REST documentation from Oracle only gives examples for creating/editing JDBC datasources, which I am not looking for:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WLRUR/examples.htm#WLRUR208

Are there control capabilities? Is there maybe better REST API documentation?

Answer (score 0):

REST Dokumentation for JDBC-Actions:
[https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/weblogic-server/12.2.1.4/wlrsr/api-jdbc-data-source-runtime-jdbc-service-runtime-jdbc-data-source-runtime-mbeans-actions.html][1]

This works on my machine (with Managed Server):
-X POST
${wlUrl}/management/weblogic/latest/domainRuntime/serverRuntimes/${server}/JDBCServiceRuntime/JDBCDataSourceRuntimeMBeans/${datasource}/stop